# Custom UIView addTarget?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uicontrolevents

I am creating a custom `UIView`. I am wondering how can I replicate the `UIButton` behavior on this `UIView`.

I would like to be able to call `addTarget` to it like an `UIButton`.

I know that I can subclass `UIControl` and call

```
self.sendActionsForControlEvents(UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside);
```

but I would like to do it on an `UIView` since I am designing it on a **XIB** file.

Comment: Add UIControl with custom view bounds with Backgound color clear then add target that UIControl otherwise add TapGesture to the View

Answer (score 16):

There is an easy way to achieve this.

> 1. Go to Interface builder of your class
> 2. Select the view u want to add action
> 3. open IDENTITY INSPECTOR, change class from UIView to 'UIControl'.

Now u can add any IBAction method to this view.

Its working like charm.
happy coding.
hope it may help

**Update**

> its working in xCode 10.1 and swift 4+

Comment: this is brilliant and much nicer than the other solutions. it's easy to create a custom button this way, just as an example. This should be the correct answer because the touchUpInsideEvent was requested in the question

Comment: great answer.. except that it assumes that everyone uses storybuilder to build UI. False.

Comment: This is brilliant, and it does work without IB, if you just declare your class to inherit from UIControl instead of UIView, you can call addTarget!

Comment: @biomiker you're right, its your choice to use IB or call addTarget!! Cheers happy coding.

Answer (score 10):

This will be better if we talking about swift3 or swift 4

```
let gesture:UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(targetViewDidTapped))
gesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
targetView?.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
targetView?.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)
```

Answer (score 8):

you can use `UITapGestureRecognizer`, add it on view programmatically as follows

```
self.userInteractionEnabled = true
let gesture:UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(viewTapped))
gesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
self.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)
```

and implement the selector, You can also add gesture to view using xib or Interface Builder file.

Answer (score 6):

In Swift 4 there is new syntax of init **UITapGestureRecognizer**:

```
let gesture:UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("viewTapped:"))
// or declare like this
let gesture:UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(YourClass.viewTapped(gesture:)))
yourView.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)
```